# how to remove login process from a website hosted on apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, hosting, ubuntu-12.04, website

I am running ubuntu 12.04 server and i try to host a website which i copied from another server. 
When I now try to connect locally with ip `xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/mywebsite`

a window opens and i have to type in credentials

my ubuntu account does not work here, so what do i need?
i didn't setup any .htaccess or .htpwd

is there anyone who has an idea ? Do you need more information ? so let me know, i can add.

Comment: I solved my problem :) , the password protection was comming from the page itself using php... I just read that out of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the Apache [Authentication and Authorization](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html) documentation then work through your site's configuration looking for relevant directives.

These will most likely be related to [mod_auth_basic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) but looking for files containing the `AuthType` directive would be a good start.